# Python FastAPI: Uploading Text file gives internal server error

Tags: python, file-upload, multipart, internal-server-error, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI to write an API to upload text files and to read the txt file contents.

```
@app.post('/read_txt_file', response_class=PlainTextResponse)
async def upload_file_and_read(file: UploadFile = File(...)
                      , fileExtension: str = Form(...)):
 
    if(fileExtension == 'txt'):
        raw_txt = readTxt(file)
        raw_txt = raw_txt.decode()

    return raw_txt


def readTxt(file):
    return file.read()
```

This code above throws internal server error. Can I know how to correct it?

Logs:

> File
> "/home/readerProject/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py",
> line 183, in app
> dependant=dependant, values=values, is_coroutine=is_coroutine   File
> "/home/readerProject/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py",
> line 133, in run_endpoint_function
> return await dependant.call(**values)
>
> File "/home/readerProject/api.py", line 28, in upload_file_and_read
> raw_txt = raw_txt.decode()
>
> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'decode'
> /home/readerProject/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py:396:
> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UploadFile.read' was never awaited
> self.transport.close() RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the
> object allocation traceback

Comment: `raw_txt = await raw_txt.decode()` instead of `raw_txt = raw_txt.decode()` ?

Comment: why do we need await ? most importantly when do we have to use await ?

Comment: You are using a coroutine so you definitely need to use await like @ArakkalAbu mentioned, since it is not a function and you can't directly return it,   See [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the `readTxt(...)` function with ***`await`*** syntax as

```
raw_txt = await readTxt(file)
         ^^^^^^^
```

*Minimal verifiable example*

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/read_txt_file')
async def upload_file_and_read(
        file: UploadFile = File(...),
):
    if file.content_type.startswith("text"):
        text_binary = await readTxt(file) # call `await`
        response = text_binary.decode()
    else:
        # do something
        response = file.filename

    return response


def readTxt(file):
    return file.read()
```

As a side note, you can retrieve the *context type* by inspecting the **`file.content_type`** which can be used to identify the file extension.